# Records of average wind speed (monthly/annual) for different European cities

Tags: weather, wind

I have been trying to find statistics concerning mean annual wind speeds for a number of European cities. Surprisingly, these averages are hard to find in a single source, such as the obvious go-to places: Accuweather, windy.com, etc.

I'd be interested to compare these values for cities across different countries, thus a single country's records would not be of that much help, but I even struggled to find those.

I recall some cities` Wikipedia pages used to list average wind speed for each month, under the Climate section, from various distributed sources; I struggled to find an example to list here though, which makes be believe those sources were in the end not all reliable.

https://globalwindatlas.info/ does have a worldwide map with average wind-speed data, but that data does not seem to survive the simple sanity check of seeing whether cities notorious for their high winds (e.g. Wellington NZ) indeed have higher values than cities with little wind (e.g. Graz AT, Brasov RO).

I'd be very surprised if meteo stations don't keep records of wind speeds, which could then be indexed by various sites. DOes anyone know how I can access that information?

Comment: This page has climate data for about 50 cites. [Climate variables for cities in Europe from 2008 to 2017](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/sis-urban-climate-cities?tab=form).

Comment: Thank you, that's already quite useful! I wonder if even more granular data is available anywhere (smaller cities). In fact, many of those 50 cities are not really among the big ones in the EU at all, so they must have had other criteria (perhaps just data availability).

Comment: For the US, https://www.climate.gov/maps-data/dataset/average-wind-speeds-map-viewer appears to have that information (not sure how hard it is to extract info for specific places).

Comment: With the cities notorious for wind - it might simply be that they have more windy days than other places, not necessarily higher average wind speed. For example it could be that WLG has 10 days with 10 km/h wind, while GRZ has only 2 days, but those days were 50 km/h, but the rest were not windy. I would have thought airports would be the places to look for wind data, but it may not be accessible.

Comment: I am not aware of a European service which provides that data for different countries in a standard form, but I am sure there local services for each country, like the "Deutscher Wetterdienst" for Germany.